# Hive import using sqoop from Mysql taking too long

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm using hive and sqoop on top of hadoop in Ubuntu 18.04.

Hadoop, sqoop and Hive are working as expected but whenever I'm trying to import a data into Hive database I created, the job is halting for too long.

**Sqoop command used:**

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/project? \
--zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL \
--username hiveuser \
-P \
--table rooms \
-- hive-import \
--hive-database sqoop \
--hive-table room_info
```

Answer (score 0):

you can expedite the process using multiple mappers. for that you need to find out the column which has evenly distributed data and use that column as `--split-by <column_name>` and increase your mappers using `-m <count>` option.

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/project? \
--zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL \
--username hiveuser \
-P \
--table rooms \
-- hive-import \
--hive-database sqoop \
--hive-table room_info
--split-by <column_name>
-m 5
```

Please read the following page to understand more in details.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html

particularly this topic: **7.2.4. Controlling Parallelism**